# Why is the application not using my connection string?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

**Question.**
Why is the application not using my connection string?

**Used by:**

- Server - (LocalDB) \ MSSQLLocalDB;
- Entity Framework (EF);
- WPF Framework.

  **Goal.**
  Make the application work with the database `NORTHWINDC.MDF`.

**Description.**
 I am passing a connection string
`сonnectionStringStart = @" Data Source = (localdb)\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog = NORTHWINDC.MDF; Integrated Security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True ";`
into the constructor of the class
`class ProductContext: DbContext`.

I am running the application.
 I get a connection string: 
`Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=WpfAppFrm.ProductContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

**Result.**
The application creates the database `WpfAppFrm.ProductContext` and each time it runs it works with the database`WpfAppFrm.ProductContext`.
 
**Category.cs**

```
// 
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WpfAppFrm
{
    [Table("Categories")]
    public class Category
    {        
        public Category()
        {
            // this.Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // public virtual ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; private set; }

    }
}
```

**ProductContext.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WpfAppFrm
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        // public ProductContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        public string ConnectionString_test { get; set; }
        public ProductContext(string сonnectionString)
        {
            this.ConnectionString_test = сonnectionString;
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        // public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
//
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WpfAppFrm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static string сonnectionStringStart;
        private ProductContext _context;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            сonnectionStringStart = @"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=NORTHWINDC.MDF;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            _context = new ProductContext(сonnectionStringStart);
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource categoryViewSource =
                ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("categoryViewSource")));

                _context.Categories.Load();

                BindingList<Category> _studBindList = _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();

                categoryViewSource.Source = _context.Categories.Local;

                AddEntity();
                // GetAll();
                string сonnectionStringStartDuplicate = сonnectionStringStart;
                string connectionStringResult1 = _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
                string connectionStringResult2 = _context.ConnectionString_test;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void AddEntity()
        {
            Category category = new Category
            {
                Name = "Name_Category_4"
            };

            _context.Categories.Add(category);
            string connectionString_str = _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void GetAll()
        {
            _context.Categories.Load();

            BindingList<Category> _studBindList = _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Installing the Entity Framework**
[image]

**Database `NORTHWINDC.MDF`**
[image]

**Database `WpfAppFrm.ProductContext`**
[image]

**The result of debugging the application.**
 [image]

**The result of the application.**
[image]

**Application tree.**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having property to store connection string like here

```
public string ConnectionString_test { get; set; }
public ProductContext(string сonnectionString)
{
    this.ConnectionString_test = сonnectionString;
}
```

you need to pass connection string to the base constructor of `DbContext`, which actually uses it

```
public ProductContext(string сonnectionString) : base(connectionString)
{
}
```